# method group filter null values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following code:

```
IEnumerable<DestinationResult> destinations =
        _repository.GetDestinationData();

IEnumerable<Destination> finalDestinations = 
        destinations.Select(GetAdditionalDestinationInfo);

private Destination GetAdditionalDestinationInfo(DestinationResult d){ /* CODE */}
```

How can I still use the method group call (Select(GetAdditionalDestinationInfo)) and filter out the null values that might be returned from GetAdditionalDestinationInfo (without having to call the method again to check for null in a where clause).

Something like:

```
   IEnumerable<Destination> finalDestinations = 
        destinations.Select(GetAdditionalDestinationInfo != null)
```

Comment: Why? Why do you want to avoid anonymous methods / lambdas?

Comment: If you add a where after the current select, you'd be calling it on the results of `GetAdditionalDestinationInfo`, the function itself wouldn't be called an extra time (enumerating it more than once without doing someting like a ToList would), so you can safely do `destinations.Select(GetAdditionalDestinationInfo).Where(res=>res!=null);`

Comment: Or are you looking for an enumeration that uses the original destination if `GetAdditionalDestinationInfo` returns null (which could be done with `destinations.Select(d => GetAdditionalDestinationInfo(d) ?? d)` )  Then again, the default could be returned inside GetAdditionalDestinationInfo itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Select` maps input records to output records, one by one - there's no opportunity for filtering. Instead, you want to add another `Where`:

```
IEnumerable<Destination> finalDestinations = 
    destinations
     .Select(GetAdditionalDestinationInfo)
     .Where(i => i != null);
```